# Book title of a girl with hidden powers when genetic engineering is a staple

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, genetic-engineering

Sorry but I only remember two main events that got stuck in my head.
1- Someone tries to rape her and she manages to get away but she doesn't know how she did it. (Some capability she wasn't aware of)
2- She enters a place where there were a standing genetically-modified being and sees some extrange movement in the crotch. Only to realize the being was hermaphrodite and it was actually having sex with itself.

Yeah, I know. But it was a shelf book, no some porn story. I read it in the '90s.

Comment: By "get off" do you mean get away? The phrase you use has unfortunate slang implications in the context you are using it.

Comment: Oops!. I'll use your suggestion, then. English is not my mother language, you know?. Thanks.

Comment: I remember this story too, but any details beyond those you mention elude me. Frustrating!